# Laravel8で外部サイトに移動して戻るとsessionの取得ができない。

Tags: laravel

以下のようなシステムを開発中です。

1. laravelアプリでsessionを保存

   - `session()->put('key', 'value');`
2. 決済の外部サイトへ移動(いわゆるリンクタイプ)
3. 決済完了後、再度laravelアプリに戻る。
4. `session('key')`で取得しようとしても取得できない。

SESSION_DRIVERはfileでファイルの中身を見ると書き込んだセッションの情報は記録されているのですが、取得ができません。
`storage/framework/sessions/TAwxSw9xdWqun3okjgfpuwgRjkZnZmXDIKUFDIn3`

- 上記手順で「1」のあとlaravelアプリ内ですと別のページでもセッションの取得ができます。
- 外部サイトに移動して戻るとセッションが取得できなくなってしまいます。うまく取得する方法はありますか？

Comment: [Samesite](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite)の値は何になっていますか

Comment: `config/session.php`が'same_site' => 'lax'になっていたので'same_site' => nullにしたらsession取得ができました。これで運用上いいのかはまた勉強しますが、ありがとうございます。